# C# Login Web Form

Tags: c#, sql, authentication, webforms

I can not figure out what I have done wrong here.  I am trying to set up a basic login form for my application that authenticates with my SQL database.  Here is the code:

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblError.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            myConnection.Open();

            try
            {
                string userID = txtUser.Text;
                string passID = txtPassword.Text;

                SqlDataReader reader = null;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserName, Password From Users WHERE UserName = @user AND Password = @pass", myConnection);

                SqlParameter userParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                SqlParameter passParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);

                userParam.Value = userID;
                passParam.Value = passID;

                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader["UserName"].ToString() == userID && reader["Password"].ToString() == passID)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("TaskMonitor.aspx");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        lblError.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

It does not do anything whether I enter a correct username and password or incorrect.

Comment: Not an answer : I would suggest using a common database class for executing database commands and also using DataSet and DataTables instead of DataReaders.

Comment: where does it get when you're stepping through your code?

Comment: Put a condition if(count==0) display message and see if it fetches from database,

Comment: @user608576 what about Entities? or linq to sql?  DataSet/DataTable are oldschool :)

Comment: It might be good to get a COUNT instead of returning the UserName and Password. If the count is zero, there was no match. If the count is greater than zero, there was a match. There is always something returned by the query for you to act on.

Comment: @Muad'Dib Agree that DataTable and Set are oldschool. But if its being done just with .NET 2.0 I would suggest that approach.

Comment: @user608576 yup, right tool for the job and all that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when username or password is invalid, no rows are returned and your code inside `while` doesn't get executed.

You can change it to:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) From Users WHERE UserName = @user AND Password = @pass", myConnection);
/* ... init parameters etc ... */
if((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 0)
{
    // Access Denied
}
else
{
    // Access Granted
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I am still having issues.  It still does nothing.

Comment: @Matt, use debugging to check what's wrong. Place a breakpoint on command execution and check what it does, what parameters are etc. Also don't catch an Exception on the Web page with output to Console. Either don't catch it at all -- ASP.NET will display a nice page with exception details for you, or do your output to the page.

Comment: I never was getting an error so I went ahead and rebuilt it using Forms Authentication as someone recommended and it works great now.  Thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 1):

Also your page load hides the error label, might want to change it something like:

```
if (!IsPostBack) lblError.Visible = false;
```

You can also use ASP.NET's built in Form Authentication to handle the session:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userID, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

he mentions both situations

my suggession is : use a bit easier code:

```
myConnection.Open();
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from myDT", myConnection);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", user.Text);  
SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
if(reader.HasRows)  // i remember there is such a thing !
{

}

// myCommand.Parameters.Add("@user", user.Text); is false as i remember
```

Comment: ah sorry, i've written code here and forget that. thanks for warning.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you catch every error that is raised and writes it to the console, but as you said before, you are developing a web application, so there is no console. So first replace the Console.writeLine statement with Response.WriteLine, or remove the complete try and catch statement instead.

Second, if the query doesnt return any results, the complete if else statements is skipped. Its easier to just check if the reader has any results: If it has, than you fire your redirect, otherwhise, display the label